# Automation tools recommendations for E2E and integration testing a Firestore back-end application?

Tags: automated-testing, browser-automation, tools, tool-recommend

Does anybody have any experience and/or have any recommendations for automation tools for testing a suite of web applications that rely heavily on Firestore for data storage? We are currently working with Cypress.io which I really like separate from this issue, but it feels like we are constantly fighting against Cypress to make this work with all of its quirks.

So I am starting to keep my eyes open for tools I can whip up a POC to see if I can sway stakeholders to a different tool if it proves to be easier to set up and reliable for our needs.

**Our tech stack:**

Front End: React

Back End: Firestore (a little MongoDB)

Automated Testing: Currently Cypress.io, want to stick with JavaScript

Answer (score -1):

You can dismiss most of the *Cypress.io* by using:

- The [React testing tools](https://reactjs.org/docs/testing.html), such as Jest and the React Testing Library - for fronted testing
- [Pact](https://docs.pact.io/how_pact_works) for Contract Testing (consumer-driven)
- For the service testing, more details about your tech is necessary. [The database engine is not a important architectural information](https://youtu.be/o_TH-Y78tt4?t=2567). But generally, you can just create the necessary checks in the particular language your service is implemented, [based on the contracts provided by its consumer](https://docs.pact.io/getting_started#in-the-animal-service-provider-project).

E2E tools would be necessary only as a build configuration checking process, in order to verify if URLs in production are correctly setup - with basically no focus on the functionality itself (since you have already check them with the steps above.